# Creating a new column based on other columns from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling, data-munging

I have 2 dataframes:

df1

```
Name   Apples   Pears   Grapes   Peachs
James    3       5        5        2
Harry    1       0        2        9
Will     20      2        7        3
```

df2

```
Class   User   Factor  
A       Harry  3
A       Will   2
A       James  5
B       NaN    4
```

I want to create a new column in df2 called `Total` which is a list of all the columns for each user in df1, multiplied by the Factor for that user - this should only be done if they are in Class A.

This is how the final df should look

df2

```
Class   User   Factor   Total 
A       Harry  3        [3,0,6,27]
A       Will   2        [40,4,14,6]
A       James  5        [15,25,25,10]
B       NaN    4
```

This is what I tried:

```
df2['Total'] = list(df1.Name.isin((df2.User) and (df2.Class==A)) * df2.Factor)
```

Comment: Why the result for Harry is not `[3,0,6,27]`?

Comment: just [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [multiply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html)

Comment: @Corralien, have corrected :)

Comment: @It_is_Chris I have other dataframes like df2 which will be used inputs to other dataframes hence not too sure if 'merge' is best way

Comment: @It_is_Chris has the right solution I think. In my answer I used `map` and `set_index()` to lookup some columns (it's like a merge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what your question asks:

```py
df2 = df2[df2.Class=='A'].join(df.set_index('Name'), on='User').set_index(['Class','User'])
df2['Total'] = df2.apply(lambda x: list(x * x.Factor)[1:], axis=1)
df2 = df2.reset_index()[['Class','User','Factor','Total']]
```

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[
x.strip() for x in 'Name   Apples   Pears   Grapes   Peachs'.split()], data =[
['James',    3,       5,        5,        2],
['Harry',   1,       0,        2,        9],
['Will',     20,      2,        7,        3]])
print(df)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=[
x.strip() for x in 'Class   User   Factor'.split()], data =[
['A',       'Harry',  3],
['A',       'Will',   2],
['A',       'James',  5],
['B',       np.nan,    4]])
print(df2)

df2 = df2[df2.Class=='A'].join(df.set_index('Name'), on='User').set_index(['Class','User'])
df2['Total'] = df2.apply(lambda x: list(x * x.Factor)[1:], axis=1)
df2 = df2.reset_index()[['Class','User','Factor','Total']]
print(df2)
```

Input:

```
    Name  Apples  Pears  Grapes  Peachs
0  James       3      5       5       2
1  Harry       1      0       2       9
2   Will      20      2       7       3
  Class   User  Factor
0     A  Harry       3
1     A   Will       2
2     A  James       5
3     B    NaN       4
```

Output

```
  Class   User  Factor             Total
0     A  Harry       3     [3, 0, 6, 27]
1     A   Will       2    [40, 4, 14, 6]
2     A  James       5  [15, 25, 25, 10]
```

Comment: @user341383 Do you need additional help with your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
# First lookup
factor = df2[df2['Class'] == 'A'].set_index('User')['Factor']
df1['Total'] = df1[cols].mul(df1['Name'].map(factor), axis=0).agg(list, axis=1)

# Second lookup
df2['Total'] = df2['User'].map(df1.set_index('Name')['Total'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
  Class   User  Factor             Total
0     A  Harry       3     [3, 0, 6, 27]
1     A   Will       2    [40, 4, 14, 6]
2     A  James       5  [15, 25, 25, 10]
3     B    NaN       4               NaN

>>> df1
    Name  Apples  Pears  Grapes  Peachs             Total
0  James       3      5       5       2  [15, 25, 25, 10]
1  Harry       1      0       2       9     [3, 0, 6, 27]
2   Will      20      2       7       3    [40, 4, 14, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

On-liner masochists, greetings ;)

```
df2['Total'] = pd.Series(df1.sort_values(by='Name').reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:,1:5]\
                         .mul(df2[df2.Class == 'A'].sort_values(by='User')['Factor'].reset_index(drop=True), axis=0)\
                         .values.tolist())
df2
```

Output:

| index | Class | User | Factor | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | Harry | 3 | 3,0,6,27 |
| 1 | A | Will | 2 | 15,25,25,10 |
| 2 | A | James | 5 | 40,4,14,6 |
| 3 | B | NaN | 4 | NaN |